# Specification OR clause, in and isEmpty/isNull

Tags: spring-boot, criteria-api

I have workers that have competences (driving licenses and such) and then there are mechanisms that require certain competences. Sometimes the mechanisms require no competences at all.

Currently I have a Specification with an in clause that works fine, but I would like it to also send out mechanisms that require no competences to operate.

```
public static Specification<Mechanism> hasCompetences(String searchTerm) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(searchTerm.split(",")));
            return root.join("competences").get("name").in(list);
        };
    }
```

If I have 3 mechanisms with competences like

Car | B-Category |

Van | C-Category |

Bicycle |(no data here) |

After requesting `mechanisms?competences=B-Category` it returns Car as expected, but I would like to get the Bicycle too.

Or is there a way to get all all mechanisms that don't require competences? I tried `mechanisms?competences=` but that returned `[]`.

Edit:

This is where I'm at right now:

```
public static Specification<Mechanism> hasCompetences(List<String> list) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            return cb.or(
                    cb.isEmpty(root.join("competences")),
                    root.join("competences").get("name").in(list)
            );
        };
    }
```

But the isEmpty is giving me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SetAttributeJoin]
```

Edit2:

```
public static Specification<Mechanism> hasCompetences(List<String> list) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            Join<Mechanism, Set<Competence>> competences = root.join("competences", JoinType.LEFT);
            return cb.or(
                    root.join("competences").get("name").in(list),
                    cb.isEmpty(competences)
            );
        };
    }
```

Error:

```
unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SetAttributeJoin];
```

Comment: Have you tried cb.isEmpty(root.get("competences"))

Comment: No errors, but still doesn't return mechanisms with empty competences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

1. The criteria to match empty collection is `cb.isEmpty(root.get("competences"))`
2. You need to specify left join. `root.join("competences", JoinType.LEFT)`

Without the second amendment, you make an inner join, so you will never retrieve Mechanisms with empty competences.

**Update**

You proposed

```
Join<Mechanism, Set<Competence>> competences = root.join("competences", JoinType.LEFT);
return cb.or(
    root.join("competences").get("name").in(list),
    cb.isEmpty(competences)
);
```

`isEmpty` won't work on `SetAttributeJoin` (the result of `root.join`) - look point 1. above

Try

```
Join<Mechanism, Set<Competence>> competences = root.join("competences", JoinType.LEFT);
return cb.or(
    competences.get("name").in(list),
    cb.isEmpty(root.get("competences"))
);
```

Comment: Edited again, I tried using left join. Is there something wrong with my code?